# Position an automata below another, both centered

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I want to draw two automata in a `tikz` picture. The second automaton should be below the first, and both should be centered horizontally.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % first automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (sA)               {$A$};
  \node[state,accepting] (sB) [right of=sA] {$B$};
  \path[->] (sA) edge[loop below] node {$0$} ()
            (sA) edge[bend left]  node {$1$} (sB)
            (sB) edge[bend left]  node {$0$} (sA);

  % second automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (s0) [below=15mm of sA] {$s_0$};
  \node[state]           (s1) [right of=s0]      {$s_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s2) [right of=s1]      {$s_2$};
  \path[->] (s0) edge node {$a$} (s1)
            (s1) edge node {$b$} (s2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: two automata in the same tikz picture]

How is the best way of getting the automata centered?

**EDIT**: The `standalone` class is used here only for illustration purposes. I really intend to use the `beamer` class.

Comment: An easy fix that will work in classes such as `article`, etc. (but not in `standalone`) is to dedicate a `tikzpicture` to each automaton (if you can afford it) and use `\centering`. Make sure to leave a blank line between the two `tikzpicture` environments.

Comment: In the real document I am using the `beamer` class, and the idea of using two separate `tikzpicture`s works, even with overlayed frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy fix that will work in most classes (other than `standalone`) is to dedicate a `tikzpicture` to each automaton (if you can afford it) and use the `\centering` declaration.

Make sure to leave a blank line between the two `tikzpicture` environments. You can also add some vertical space between the two.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % first automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (sA)               {$A$};
  \node[state,accepting] (sB) [right of=sA] {$B$};
  \path[->] (sA) edge[loop below] node {$0$} ()
            (sA) edge[bend left]  node {$1$} (sB)
            (sB) edge[bend left]  node {$0$} (sA);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % second automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (s0) [below=15mm of sA] {$s_0$};
  \node[state]           (s1) [right of=s0]      {$s_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s2) [right of=s1]      {$s_2$};
  \path[->] (s0) edge node {$a$} (s1)
            (s1) edge node {$b$} (s2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{One automaton, two automata\ldots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: as Gonzalo Medina points out, there is no point in using a float environment, since the class used is `beamer`. In that case, combining `minipage` and `\centering` will do the trick. A `center` environment can also be used, but takes more vertical space than the latter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % first automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (sA)               {$A$};
  \node[state,accepting] (sB) [right of=sA] {$B$};
  \path[->] (sA) edge[loop below] node {$0$} ()
            (sA) edge[bend left]  node {$1$} (sB)
            (sB) edge[bend left]  node {$0$} (sA);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1em}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % second automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (s0) [below=15mm of sA] {$s_0$};
  \node[state]           (s1) [right of=s0]      {$s_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s2) [right of=s1]      {$s_2$};
  \path[->] (s0) edge node {$a$} (s1)
            (s1) edge node {$b$} (s2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the OP is not interested in a floating object, you could also suggest enclosing the two `tikzpicture`s inside a `minipage` with `\centering` or alternatively, inside a `center` environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Done.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use two figure environments and separate the TikZ pictures.
EDIT: I see `jubobs` proposed something similar.
The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % first automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (sA)               {$A$};
  \node[state,accepting] (sB) [right of=sA] {$B$};
  \path[->] (sA) edge[loop below] node {$0$} ()
            (sA) edge[bend left]  node {$1$} (sB)
            (sB) edge[bend left]  node {$0$} (sA);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=15mm, auto]
  % second automaton
  \node[state,initial]   (s0) [below=15mm of sA] {$s_0$};
  \node[state]           (s1) [right of=s0]      {$s_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (s2) [right of=s1]      {$s_2$};
  \path[->] (s0) edge node {$a$} (s1)
            (s1) edge node {$b$} (s2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Seems like the easies solution to me...

Comment: One problem with your solution is that the two `figure`s may "float apart", thereby defeating the OP's original goal. Keeping the two `tikzpicture`s within the same `figure` environment is preferable, here.

Comment: Apparently the OP is using the beamer class, It shouldn't be to hard to put both figures on a slide. Although I agree your solution  would have its benefits in certain situations. It's really dependent on what the exact situation is I suppose :-)